# In sharepoint 2010 ajax returns in error in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-chrome, sharepoint-2010

I am using rest for retreiving data from sharepoint 2010 list using ../_vti_bin/listdata.svc by jquery ajax. below is the code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",    
        url: "../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/"+listName+"?$select=Title",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",         
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
        success: generateCarousal,
        error: alertError,
        //complete:afterCompletion
    });


function generateCarousal(data)
{   
    if(data.d.results.length>0)
    {    
        var carousalDiv=item.Title;

    }
    else
    { alert("Data not found")}
}


function alertError(jqXHR)
{
    if (jqXHR.status == 200 && jqXHR.statusText == "OK") {
        alert(typeof  jqXHR.responseText)

  }
  else {
        alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
  }     
}
```

This is working fine in IE i.e I am getting json object in success but for chrome it enters into error with status 200 and statustext "ok". And also responsetext is giving proper data in string format and I am unable to convert it into json using jquery.parseJson.

Can anyone please explain why it is not working in chrome and what are the possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try success code in the call itself like

```
success: function(data) {
     //Write your code here
    if(data.d.results.length>0)
    {    
        var carousalDiv=item.Title;
    }
    else
    { 
        alert("Data not found")
    }
    },
  error: function() {
     alert('An error occurred');
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: it is working in ie but same thing is not working in chrome. So I need the same thing should be working in chrome also.

Comment: Have you tried success code written inside ajax call rather than defining another function like in my example
Earlier i faced same issue with firefox